# Embedded tweets not displaying properly in vue

Tags: html, vue.js

I am using django as my backend and vue frontend. I have a model that has a richtexteditor, and in my save method, it converts tweet links to embedded html tweets instead, I do not believe this part is important, just thought that I would need to provide some preface as to what my problems are. So within vue, I have a div with v-html set to the contents of the model. The contents of the div match everything else I have saved except the tweets won't display properly. The contents of the tweets are displayed without the container, profile image etc.

I have tried copying the embedded tweet html in the inspect tool in chrome and used w3schools tryit editor, and it loaded properly

HTML for embedded tweet:

```html
<blockquote class="twitter-tweet" data-theme="dark"><p lang="en" dir="ltr">Thank you all for replying to our tweets. I think I’ll do just one more for the night... I have to go to prepare for tomorrow’s festivities! .</p>&mdash; AMNotify (@AMNotify) <a href="https://twitter.com/AMNotify/status/1171218606371332101?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">September 10, 2019</a></blockquote>
<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
```

How it is displayed:

Thank you all for replying to our tweets. I think I’ll do just one more for the night... I have to go to prepare for tomorrow’s festivities! .— AMNotify (@AMNotify) [September 10, 2019](https://twitter.com/AMNotify/status/1171218606371332101?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw)

How it should be displayed: 
https://jsfiddle.net/z7wgLqcb/

Answer (score 0):

Solved, needed to add `<script async src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" charset="utf-8"></script>` to index.html